# Why are dermatologists working on coronavirus cases?

Tags: covid-19, practice-of-medicine, coronavirus, hospital, icu-intensive-care-unit

I saw a report that dermatologists are working on coronavirus cases.

Does this mean that all kinds of medical doctors are licensed to care for COVID-19 patients?

So a neurologist can help, cardiologist can help, a urologist / penile enhancement surgeon can help, and also gynecologists?

What about dentists?

Anyone practicing medicine of any form can go to New York City to help right now?

To be clear, I mean treating COVID-19 patients at the hospitals, in the ER, ICU, etc.

**Note.** An emergency text message was sent to us, urging any and all available doctors to report to New York City, because of the urgent need for doctors. So, it sounds like even a dermatologist might be working in the ICU at this point. Hence my question.

Comment: Why do you think a license is needed to treat covid-19?

Comment: @America thanks for the edits, I'm looking forward to reading an answer ...

Comment: Who is"us" in the text message? The whole city? State?

Comment: @GrahamChiu I'm pretty sure the entire United States got this text message ...

Comment: @user19194 I'm in the US and I didn't receive it, nor did anyone else I know in the US. Who sent it? It's beginning to smell like you might have received a scam.

Comment: @CareyGregory It was one of those alert things, a message blasted out to us, with an alarm sounding off on our phones.  After reading the alert, it vanishes and doesn't remain as a text message.  It seemed pretty legit to me, unfortunately ...

Comment: Does the USA even have that capability? It sounds like it would have to be in a federal govt level.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes, I'm pretty sure I read about it on the news online somewhere, too. 
 Almost anyone with any cell phone carrier got the message, apparently.

Comment: Reference otherwise it's just a myth!

Comment: The federal government does have the capability to send such an alert to every cell phone nationwide. However, since I didn't receive it and no one else I know received it, I don't think it was the national system this article describes:

https://www.cnn.com/2018/10/03/politics/cellphone-federal-emergency-alert-system-test/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/get-involved-how-you-can-help

> Governor Cuomo is calling on health care professionals, schools of public health or medicine and PPE products providers and manufacturers to come forward to support the state’s response.

and

> We are looking for qualified health, mental health, and related professionals who are interested in supporting the state’s response

All of the specialities you list in your question are health care professionals and have completed basic training in hospitals.  The NY govt will triage those to see which qualifications are best suited to what positions are available.

Comment: Yes, NY is asking for medical professionals to volunteer. That's widely known. But I'm suspicious of the text OP reports.

Comment: I'm skeptical too. No one I know living in the USA received any message.

Comment: @GrahamChiu see my comment to Carey, above ^ thanks

Comment: Di you live in NY?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes, near hundreds of doctors and members of the army (the National Guard).  Many of them are from states such as Missouri, Maryland, South Carolina etc., and they're living in nearby hotels.

Comment: So maybe only NY got that text?

Comment: @GrahamChiu I spoke with many of them, during my project with them.  Many of them do not even know how to get around Manhattan / New York City.  They're literally waking up, and catching a bus to whichever hospital needs them on that day.

Comment: @GrahamChiu possibly ...